# Did Tasha Yar bring Spot?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I've just stumbled upon this screen capture of Tasha Yar escaping a rape gang with a cat:

[image: Tasha and the cat]

This cat strongly resembles Data's cat, Spot:

[image: spot the cat]

What happened to Tasha Yar's cat, did she bring him to the Enterprise?

Comment: If memory serves, she is just about to send the cat away, because "something terrible is about to happen" (I think, that's what she said). That doesn't mean much, since cats tend to return to their owner... If Tasha is the owner. She doesn't appear to be at home. So why would she bring her cat there? Maybe she just stumbled upon it. In that case the cat probably won't/can't return to her.

Comment: I don't think "incredibly resembles Spot" is a good  interpretation here.  Cat markings and colours are confined to a small-ish handful of types, so it's quite common to see different cats with similar markings (just take a walk outside any day and you'll see plenty).

Comment: @JimmyShelter but, as there are not many cats in ST universe, this could have been a nice explanation of how Data got Spot.

Comment: @madfriend - it could have been, yes, but theories about "wouldn't it have been cool if..." are not what this site is about.

Comment: @JimmyShelter - I've changed it to "strongly resembles" on the grounds that ginger cats all do look pretty similar...

Comment: @madfriend: I doubt there are any less cats in the ST universe than in our current universe. Nothing in the series or films points to that. The fact that only few of the protagonists whose quarters we see at all have a cat for a pet rather matches with our present world, where by far not every household has a cat (probably less so "households" on a mobile basis such as ships). I think it would be incredibly contrived if of all cats, the cat that Tasha once met/had in a somewhat undefined time back on her homeworld were Data's Spot. And with that in mind, we cannot even say for sure whether ...

Comment: ... "Spot" was the same cat during the whole run of TNG, given its [changing appearance](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/spot.htm).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper sorry, I did not made myself clear: by "ST universe" I meant "what is observed in series". There are not many cats shown in ST series.

Comment: @madfriend: Indeed, with that I agree. As we see very few cats overall, it is extremely unlikely that we ever get to see the same cat in two different contexts.

Comment: @madfriend You're assuming that the people in the background are a rape gang. They could just as easily be a rescue party looking for their pet cat who turned up missing. Food their on Turkana IV is obviously in short supply and she does look to be throttling the critter... I doubt that cat survived long enough to make it into Data's care.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### In-universe

Within the Episode "[Where None Have Gone Before](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/106.txt), Tasha Yar appears to have released the cat sometime before she was rescued by the crew of the USS Cochrane;

> HOLDING in the same position what is now a VERY BEGRIMED KITTEN while
>   Tasha herself is dressed very differently in TATTERED CAST-OFF
>   CLOTHING, HER FACE BEGRIMED TOO, HER HAIR ASKEW. **She puts the kitten
>   down.**
>
> **TASHA:** **Now, run. This isn't a safe place at all.**

In the TNG Novel "*[Survivors](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Survivors)*" it is explicitly clear that her cat was later killed by a rape gang, possibly the same one we see in the TV show.

> "Revenge had cost her her chance—two men grabbed her from behind,
>   while their leader captured the cat in a hammy hand, then wrested the
>   knife from the girl and **before her eyes gutted the only living being
>   who cared for her**."

### Out of Universe:

The cat seen in TNG: "Where None have gone before" was provided by [Birds & Animals Unlimited](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Birds_&_Animals_Unlimited) whereas the various ginger versions of Spot (of which there were at least four seen on screen) were provided by [Critters of the Cinema](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Critters_of_the_Cinema) so it's highly unlikely that they would have used the same cat.

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

**The timing doesn't really work**. Tasha escaped her home planet in 2352, and the cat looks to be a young adult in that scene.

**If we discount the novels (where the cat died before she escaped), then it's possible that Tasha could have taken it with her**. But she didn't join Starfleet until 2363. The cat would have been 11 years old at that point: still well within the realm of plausibility, but we're no longer talking about a young cat. The episode where Spot first appears, "Data's Day", seems to have taken place in 2367: four years later. **Spot's not a kitten, even in that episode, but she looks a lot younger than 15**. In fact, Spot seems to still be alive as of 2379, and while 27-year-old cats are not unheard of even today, that's getting to be a bit of a stretch.

All of that said, **it *is* possible that Data might have chosen this type of cat because it reminded him of Tasha**. Maybe she talked with him about her experiences, and a ginger cat came up somewhere in those. Or, if Tasha did bring it with her, then he might have met it, or even taken care of it after Tasha's death, like you say. But it's still too old to be Spot: if Data ever took care of Tasha's cat, then it must have died at some point (which would also explain why we never see him with two cats). Spot is a different cat.

Comment: Are we pretending that it's the same cat (and the same age of cat) throughout the whole show?

Comment: Certainly Spot wasn't played by the same cat throughout the show, but it's probably safe to assume that the animals who played her resembled the authors' intent for the character.

Comment: Even the writers acknowledge that they mucked up in getting a different breed and age of cat for the later series'

Answer (score 0):

[image: Tasha looks at the cat that suddenly appeared on the bridge]In that same episode, in the present day, a similar-looking cat also appears on the bridge right before Tasha has her flashback.

It is never stated in the show where or how Data got Spot. The only things we know for certain based on the show are:

- A ginger tabby appeared both in Tasha’s flashback and in the present on the Enterprise bridge in Where No One Has Gone Before.
- Data later is later shown to have a pet cat named Spot.
- Spot originally appears to be a red/orange Somali cat, and is referred to as “he” for several episodes.
- Spot later becomes a ginger tabby cat.
- Eventually Spot has kittens, so either Data incorrectly identified her gender, or this cat is somehow capable of changing genders.
- Spot is still alive approx 12 years later, during Star Trek Nemesis. We don’t know how old this makes him/her as we were never told Spot’s age.
- The above makes it unlikely Spot would be Tasha’s original cat brought from home, as she left her planet in 2352, so that cat would be *at least* 27 years old by Nemesis, if it were born the same year she left.
- The present-day scenes in Where No One Has Gone Before take place in 2379, 15 years before Nemesis, and as mentioned, a manifestation of a cat *does* also appear then. It is unknown what happened to that cat, however all of the other anomalies appeared to vanish by the end of the episode.

There is plenty to speculate about here and you could use the theory that Spot is actually the deep space anomaly cat to neatly explain the plot holes of her mysteriously changing breed and gender (and personally I like the idea), but it’s not something that is ever actually stated or implied in the show.

Comment: IIRC the cat on the bridge _triggered_ Yar's flashback.  You list a lot of details, most of which are covered in the other answers, without actually answering the question.  Is Spot the cat that Yar held in the flashback or not?

Comment: I included an answer at the end. My point was that question doesn’t have a clear yes or no answer in canon. Neither Data nor any other character ever discusses Spot’s origins. Best we can do is speculate on what the writers intended/what seems most likely based on the given context. “It wasn’t intended to be the same cat” may be a pretty safe guess based on the above details, but it’s still just a guess.